# is there way to get and set token to local storage?

Tags: angular, authentication, protractor, jwt

I'm writing e2e tests on http:localhost/ using protractor since we are only developing front-end app. 
I have to login into clients integration and manually copy token value from local storage and pass it to custom login method witch I created.
Is there away to automate this login process?

Any suggestion would be great

So far I have tried window.localStorage.getItem() and window.localStorage.setItem()

```
public static Login(): void {
    browser.get('login url');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('user');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('submit')).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    const token: string = window.localStorage.getItem('AuthenticationToken');
    browser.get('error page');
    window.localStorage.setItem('AuthenticationToken', token);
    browser.get('home page');
}
```

I get this errors:

- Failed: window is not defined
- Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.

Comment: Yes you can set and get from local Storage `localStorage.setItem('Auth_token', data);`

Answer (score 1):

According to @Abhishek items of a local storage can be set and gotten using `localStorage.setItem('Auth_token', data)` and `localStorage.getItem(keyName)`

However, from my understanding this can be done only from the browser's console, not from protractor script. Thus, if you want to accomplish the same results in your protractor script you could do the following:

```
browser.executeScript(`return window.localStorage.getItem(keyName);`);
```

Or if you intend to use local storage a lot, implement a new `local-storage.js` module as follow:

```
function LocalStorage () {

    this.get = async function () {
        let storageString = await browser.executeScript("return JSON.stringify(window.localStorage);");
        return JSON.parse(storageString);
    };

    this.clear = async function () {

        return browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.clear();");
    };

    this.getValue = async function (key) {

        return browser.executeScript(`return window.localStorage.getItem('${key}');`);
    };

    this.setValue = async function (key, value) {
        return browser.executeScript(`window.localStorage.setItem('${key}', '"${value}"');`);
    };
}

module.exports = new LocalStorage();
```

And then in your spec, do the following:

```
localStorage = require("./local-storage.js");

describe(`Suite: Home page`, () => {

    fit("Login to the application", async () => {

        console.log(await localStorage.getValue("calltrk-calltrk_referrer"));
        await localStorage.setValue("key", "value");
        console.log(await localStorage.getValue("key"));
        console.log(await localStorage.get());
    });
});
```

Note I solely handle Promises with `async/await` keywords. So your syntax can be different, but the approach should remain the same