# How to set the variables user and jeton of sessionStorage in e2e test protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm looking to edit sessionStorage before tests :

I tried this :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    browser.executeScript('sessionStorage.setItem("jeton", "Muthu");');
    browser.executeScript('localStorage.setItem("jeton", "Muthu");');
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('jeton', 'zefzef');
    window.localStorage.setItem('jeton', 'zefzef');
 });
```

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773013/is-there-way-to-get-and-set-token-to-local-storage/57775252#57775252

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there way to get and set token to local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773013/is-there-way-to-get-and-set-token-to-local-storage)

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov ,First ,thank you for your reply, I tried browser.executeScript('sessionStorage.setItem("token","test") , when I refresh I see the new value of token,I have to enter two variables token and user that contain a Json , when I try to set the user variable and a real token , I got an error message : .

Comment: first, try to add `await` to the statement since `browser.executeScript()` is a promise, second which error message do you get?

Comment: this is the error message : Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.

Comment: Probably what happens is you open the page inside `it` block, only after you open the page, `localStorage` is created. But you're trying to access it in `beforeEach ` before it's created. Try to reorganize the order of actions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205856/protractor-empty-local-storage